# How to sync the develop environment and tools among Mac machines for RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I have many mac os devices (Mac Pro, Macbook) and develop RoR on those devices.

How could I sync the environment among those Machines (e.g. brew , rvm, mysql, any modules) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be worth considering virtualizing your development environment using [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/). Ryan Bates from Rails Casts did an [intro screen cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/292-virtual-machines-with-vagrant). Another option is to create a shell script that configures your environment automatically. I use a personal one found [here](https://github.com/ksylvest/setup) that sets up Postgres, Rbenv, and a handful.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use different machines instead of going with vagrant as Kevin suggested, You might want to give [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) a try. Since you are familiar with RoR. I am assuming you are familiar with ruby. Chef cookbooks are basically ruby code. You can easily find chef solo cookbooks for installing your requirements just by searching on google like "chef postgresql for osx". You can also write your own cookbooks after following basic documentation on opscode.

Knife solo is a wrapper around chef solo to install cookbooks on remote machines. Here is an introduction to [knife solo and chef solo](http://devops.mashion.net/2011/08/04/chef-solo-basics/).

Though, you'll still need a CM tool like chef even if you go with vagrant option.